# webmatrix c# if statement embedded in foreach causes syntax error

Tags: c#, razor, foreach, webmatrix

I've read several similar posts but they do not fix my issue. Here is the code that works fine.

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var row in db.Query(readSchedule,dt,pd2))
    {      
        sid = @row.ScheduleId;
        pd = @row.Date.ToString();
        cn = @row.CourseName;
        cut = @row.Cutoff;
        cost = @row.Cost;
        fa = @row.Fadd;
        var dow=@row.Date.DayOfWeek;
        pp=@row.PrePay;
        <li><a href="/MyFiles/Signup1.cshtml?   &sid=@sid&pd=@pd&cn=@cn&cut=@cut&cost=@cost&fa=@fa&pp=@pp">
               @cn on @pd (@dow)</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```

When I add the `if` statement shown below, I get the syntax error message `; expected`.

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var row in db.Query(readSchedule,dt,pd2))
    {      
        sid = @row.ScheduleId;
        pd = @row.Date.ToString();
        cn = @row.CourseName;
        cut = @row.Cutoff;
        cost = @row.Cost;
        fa = @row.Fadd;
        var dow=@row.Date.DayOfWeek;
        pp=@row.PrePay;
if (pp=="")
{pp="none";}
        <li><a href="/MyFiles/Signup1.cshtml?   &sid=@sid&pd=@pd&cn=@cn&cut=@cut&cost=@cost&fa=@fa&pp=@pp">
               @cn on @pd (@dow)</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: This seems a bug in the designer to me. Can you check if the code compiles and works?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the razor compiler is perfect, especially when asked to switch back and forth between html and C#.  That being said, I would probably write the line in so a way that no switching is necessary:

```
pp = @( (@row.PrePay == "" ? "none" : row.PrePay   )
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know how to write an if statement in this format so you helped in two ways.